# How can I execute a command line command from a C++ program

Tags: c++, ubuntu

How can I execute the command line "asterisk -rx "reload"" in c++? Please help. I need an example. I am working on ubuntu server and I want to execute this command line from a user (inside a webservice).

Need help
Appreciate

Comment: Did you really mean C++/CLI, of did you mis-interpret the tag [c++-cli] to mean "C++ command line interface"? Is there actually a C++/CLI implementation for Linux?

Answer (score 33):

Sounds like a trivial use-case for the `system()` function:

```
system("asterisk -rx reload");
```

If you need very fine-grained control of the child process there are better ways, but this is simple to get going.

This call starts a shell (such as bash) to run the command, which is why I removed the quotes around `reload`; they're pointless for a single word and will be removed by the shell and never seen by the started program, anyway.

Comment: This is good, an alternative method could be fork/exec to (requires more effort but more powerful overall)

Comment: i tested it byt is not wkiring

Comment: i have a web service on a server and i trying to call this method from the user but the asterisk is not reloading. why? need help plz

Comment: @AngelDream: The program that calls the `system` function must have the correct privileges to execute the `asterisk` program. For example, if your program is running as a normal user, but `asterisk` requires a root user, then the `system` call will not work because the your program is not allowed to execute `asterisk`.

Answer (score 6):

[`system("asterisk -rx \"reload\"")`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) would probably work, if you don't need standard output or error from the process.

If you need results from the process, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) is an example of using C's [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), or you could look at [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) for a C++ approach.