# How to open command prompt and insert command using c++

Tags: cmd, c++-cli

Currently I am working on project of Image processing using c++. I found solution which requires use of Command prompt.Can you please tell me syntax of some portion of it?

Since my C++ skills aren't that great I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832326/how-can-i-execute-a-command-line-command-from-a-c-program

Comment: what OS? some compiler/IDEs has linbuild functions to run cmd. You can always start new proccess with cmd.exe or what ever ... and then hook to its handle ... or use pipes etc

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. Do you want to run a command? Do you want to run a command with a bunch of command line parameters? Do you want to pop up a command prompt window for the user to type in? Do you want to launch a command, pipe the results to a second command, and redirect those results to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use system() function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  return system("dir");
}
```

Comment: When I am writing following syntax 
return system("dir");
It refers to my desktop location.But I want this pointer to my C:/ drive.

Comment: I used "dir" as example. You can use any command promt instruction.

Comment: system("dir c:\\"); - lists C:/ drive